# Extracting all results from multiple Fisher test in R

Tags: r

I am performing a Fisher test over 1000 of rows in a data frame, it works fine but my script only extract the pvalue, I would like to also extract the odds ratio and confidence interval.

Here is my tiny script:

```
apply(mydata,1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x,nr=2))$p.value,$odds.ratio)
```

And here is the results when performed on one row at a time:

```
> fisher.test(try,  workspace=2e9)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  try
p-value = 0.4144
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.04686857 11.67245884
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
   1.92144
```

So my goal is to improve my one line code to extract odds ratio and confidence interval, do you guys know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
res <- t(apply(mydata,1, function(x) {x1 <-fisher.test(matrix(x, nr=2))
                        c(x1$p.value, x1$conf.int, x1$estimate)}))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 20*4, replace=TRUE), nrow=20))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(mydata,1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x,nr=2))[1:3])
```

subset 1 is the p-value, subset 2 is the confidence interval and 3 is the odds ratio

if you wanted the p-value and the odds ratio you could use

```
apply(mydata,1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x,nr=2))[c(1,3)])
```

Comment: This answers was flagged for deletion, likely because all it consists of is code without any explanation. I've declined the flag, but you should probably improve your answer by supplying some commentary. What was the problem the asker was having? How have you fixed it?